# Converting time stamps in excel to dates

Tags: excel-formula

I have a very large excel spread sheet that has a column of time stamps. Does anyone know convert that over to a date? Is there a function I can use? I tried format cell date but that doesn't work. My file is 91,568 KB. If there is a simpler way to this that would be great. I'm open to ideas.

Thank you in advance :)

P.S.
I don't know any programming languages

Comment: What kind of a timestamp is that? Milliseconds?
Internet is full of answers. Did you try some of those?
http://www.bajb.net/2010/05/excel-timestamp-to-date/

Comment: The time stamp looks like this 1234817823. When I use this website (http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm) it says Mon, 16 Feb 2009 20:57:03 GMT. My problem is how to create a function that will apply to 1 million records.

Comment: Then have a look at the link I've posted. I don't have excel, but I've tried that in Libreoffice Calc and the output is:
02/16/09 08:57 PM

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Use this formula and set formatting to the desired time format:

```
=(((COLUMN_ID_HERE/60)/60)/24)+DATE(1970,1,1)
```

Source: http://www.bajb.net/2010/05/excel-timestamp-to-date/
Tested in libreoffice

Comment: =INT(((COLUMN_ID_HERE/60)/60)/24)+DATE(1970,1,1) This works for me.. Also Note that the Timestamp should be in seconds

Comment: If you are going to display the time value according to your timezone, you should add time offset `+TIME(1,0,0)`

Comment: =INT( ( ( COLUMN_ID / 60 ) / 60 ) / 24 ) + DATE( 1970; 1; 1 )
For Microsoft Excel Online

Comment: The INT will round to the nearest day, that's probably not what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 41):

A timestamp is the elapsed time since Epoch time (01/01/1970), so basically we have to convert this time in days, and add the epoch time, to get a valid format for any Excel like spreadsheet software.

- From a timestamp in milliseconds (ex: 1488380243994)

  use this formula:

  ```
  =A1/1000/86400+25569
  ```

  with this formater:

  ```
  yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000
  ```
- From a timestamp in seconds (ex: 1488380243)

  use this formula:

  ```
  =A1/86400+25569
  ```

  with this formater:

  ```
  yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
  ```

Where `A1` is your column identifier.
Given custom formaters allow to not loose precision in displayed data, but you can of course use any other date/time one that corresponds to your needs.

Comment: Cool answer! Could you please explain why you add `25569` specifically? I know the result is correct, but I can't understand why you need to add that.

Comment: Excel counts dates from 1900.  25569 is the number of days until 1/1/1970 when unix starts.

Answer (score 30):

below formula worked form me in MS EXEL

```
=TEXT(CELL_VALUE/24/60/60/1000 + 25569,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM")
```

CELL_VALUE is timestamp in milliseconds

[here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c) is explanation for text function.

Comment: This worked for me as well, here's another example that does timezone correction if needed (example is for UTC-5): 
`=TEXT((D3/60/60/1000 + 5)/24 + 25569,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM")`

Answer (score 22):

If you get a Error 509 in Libre office you may replace `,` by `;` in the DATE() function

```
=(((COLUMN_ID_HERE/60)/60)/24)+DATE(1970;1;1)
```

Comment: This may depend on the locales settings in your OS.

Answer (score 10):

If your file is really big try to use following formula:
=A1 / 86400 + 25569

A1 should be replaced to what your need.
Should work faster than =(((COLUMN_ID_HERE/60)/60)/24)+DATE(1970,1,1) cause of less number of calculations needed.

Comment: This is a more elegant solution and also keeps the 'time' part of the timestamp (not just the date)

Answer (score 7):

```
=(((A1/60)/60)/24)+DATE(1970,1,1)+(-5/24)
```

assuming `A1` is the cell where your time stamp is located and dont forget to adjust to account for the time zone you are in (5 assuming you are on EST)

Answer (score 6):

Be aware of number of digits in epoch time. Usually they are ten (1534936923) ,then use:

```
=(A1 / 86400) + 25569
```

For thirteen digits (1534936923000) of epoch time adjust the formula:

```
=(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-3) / 86400) + 25569
```

to avoid

```
###################################
```

Dates or times that are negative or too large display as ######

See more on https://www.epochconverter.com/

Answer (score 5):

This `DATE`-thing won't work in all Excel-versions.

```
=CELL_ID/(60 * 60 * 24) + "1/1/1970"
```

is a save bet instead.
The quotes are necessary to prevent Excel from calculating the term.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @NeplatnyUdaj is right but consider that Excel want the function name in the set language, in my case German. Then you need to use "DATUM" instead of "DATE":

```
=(((COLUMN_ID_HERE/60)/60)/24)+DATUM(1970,1,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

AD ticks to datetime format: =A1/864000000000 - 109205

Answer (score 0):

i got result from this in LibreOffice Calc :

=DATE(1970,1,1)+Column_id_here/60/60/24

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
=(col_name]/60/60/24)+(col_name-1)
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this simple formula. It works.

Suppose time stamp in `A2`:

```
=DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),DAY(A2))
```

Comment: No, it does not work, unless the content of A2 is already a date rather than timestamp.