# How to convert timestamp like 1,43876E+12 to readable date and time in Excel?

Tags: excel

Help needed..
How do I convert timestamp like 1,43876E+12 to readable date and time in Excel ?
( like dd:mm:yyyy hh:mm:ss )

Formula =(((1,43876E+12/60)/60)/24)+DATE(1970;1;1) gives me 16677889,21

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting time stamps in excel to dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070868/converting-time-stamps-in-excel-to-dates)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that your timestamp is similar to the Unix time except it is in milliseconds, and not seconds.  So you need to divide your timestamp by (24*60*60*1000) and then add DATE(1970,1,1) to get an excel date.

```
=1.43876E+12/(60*60*24*1000)+DATE(1970,1,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following formula:
=A1/(60*60*24)+"1/1/1970" where A1 has the epoch timestamp. This is because the epoch time starts from Jan 1st 1970.

Answer (score 1):

1.69164E+12 is the scientific notation for the date

Don't make converting it any more complicating than necessary. The scientific value 1.69164E+12 appears to be in scientific notation, and it's likely a Unix timestamp in milliseconds. These milliseconds represent time from the date 1/1/1970.

There are 86,400,000 milliseconds in 24 hours.
3,600,000 milliseconds/hour * 24 hours = 86,400,000 milliseconds
You get the idea.

So, in excel, if the date 1/1/1970 is 0 (zero), add the number of milliseconds expressed by the scientific number to 1/1/1970 and convert them to a date and that's it.

8/10/2023 = DATE(1970,1,1) + (1.69164E+12/86400000)

We use scientific notations because these milliseconds can be huge.

Count how many seconds are in a minute: 1 min = 60 s. Count how many milliseconds are in a second: 1 s = 1,000 ms. Multiply these two numbers
to find the direct conversion between minutes and milliseconds: 1 min = 60

Willie Chaffin
Abingdon VA