# How to convert number into date-time format in excel ( i have equivalent solution achieved in R)

Tags: r, excel, excel-formula, date-format, excel-dates

[image]

Referring to the above screenshot, i'm trying to crawl data from Singapore Stock Exchange, which the web content is loaded dynamically from an API call returning json, example [here](https://api.sgx.com/negotiatedlargetrades/v1.0?order=asc&orderby=contractcode&category=futures&businessdatestart=20191205&businessdateend=20191205&pagestart=0&pageSize=250)

I'm having some problem with the dates, which is given as a number by the json. For example, `1575491760000` is supposed to be `2019-12-04 20:36:00GMT`.

After some trial and error, i've figured solution using R:

```
as.POSIXct(1575491760000/1000, origin="1970-01-01", tz = 'GMT')  
# not sure why need to divide the number by 1000 here but i guess this is the way to make it work
```

and the above code does return `"2019-12-04 20:36:00 GMT"` in R.

**However, my question is there a solution to the above conversion in Excel?** I've tried a few different ways but none of them can deal with such long data scenario (date + time format). Appreciated if anyone can provide a specific solution!

Comment: Try janitor which had a clean ecel date function and the anytime package

Comment: What you have is a timestamp and to convert that timestamp to a date in excel you can refer to it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070868/converting-time-stamps-in-excel-to-dates. I think this maybe a duplicate question of that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the Excel equivalent.

```
=DATE(1970,1,1) + 1575491760000/(1000*60*60*24)
# 12/4/19 20:36:00  with cell formatting set to   m/d/yy h:mm:ss
```

Unix time increments one for every millisecond since 1/1/1970. Excel datetimes increment one for every day since 1/1/1900.

So to convert from UNIX time to excel, divide by the number of milliseconds in a day (`1000*60*60*24`) and add to the date 1/1/70 (`25569` under the hood in Excel.)

Comment: If they have a large number of timestamps, you would want to hard code the numbers and have a relative source for the timestamp. Like so: `=25569 + A1 / 86400000`

Comment: Thanks. I tried an example using all 1,048,462 rows available to me in Excel 2016. It took about 3 seconds with hard coded numbers and about 5 seconds without. I expected there to be more speedup, but that difference could help in some contexts.