# Convert in to Time

Tags: excel

I Have date and time in below format

20201027133110

how can i calculate time in excel

Pls share the formula

Comment: Checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070868/converting-time-stamps-in-excel-to-dates

Comment: if I understood correctly this is not a timestamp but a date in the format yyyyMMddHHmmss

Answer (score 0):

[image: This image will show you how to convert a date time to timestamp]

You can try the above to convert a dateTime to timestamp

Answer (score 0):

If A1=20201027133110 then

```
B1=TIME(MOD(A1,1000000)/10000,MOD(A1,10000)/100,MOD(A1,100))
```